# Android App Custom ListView: Add new item in the most efficient way

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I am using a custom ListView, in which I need to add a new item. Since there will be a lot of items needed to be added, I want to code it in the most efficient way so the smartphone is not loosing a lot of memory. Here is the code of my custom ListView:

```
class MessageActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context context;
    String[] message;
    String time;

    MessageActivityAdapter(Context c, String[] message, String time)
    {
        super(c, R.layout.messagescreen_list_row, R.id.textView1, message);
        this.context = c;
        this.message = message;
        this.time = time;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messagescreen_list_row, parent, false);

        TextView tvMessage = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);       
        tvMessage.setText(message[position][0]);

        return row; 
    }
}
```

This is how I load the ListView on the first time:

```
adapter = new MessageActivityAdapter(this, values, time);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is how I change the text in one of the items and update the ListView:

```
adapter.message[itemPos] = newItemText;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And thats how I thought I can add a new item to the ListView. Basically I copy the old array "message" and create a new array "messageNew" which has a +1 bigger size. Then I use "messageNew" as the new array in my MessageActivityAdapter and update the adapter. The problem: copying and creating a new array costs a lot of memory. Why I don't use an ArrayList? Because later I will change the array into a multidimensional array and multidimensional ArrayLists don't exist.

```
String[] messageNew = getNewMessageArray();
adapter.message = messageNew;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I'm also not sure if changing the "message" array and using the notifyDataSetChanged() method is the best way at all...

Comment: A) "multidimensional ArrayLists don't exist" - yes they do: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>  B) Since you can't resize your Array, you should be using an ArrayList and then use adapter.add(newItemText);  C) If you're worried about efficiency, you should probably also use the ViewHolder pattern and not inflate your Views every single time getView is called: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: the problem is, that i cannot use an ArrayList as an argument when calling the superconstructor: super(c, R.layout.messagescreen_list_row, R.id.textView1, message);